# Invoke methods in parallel based on condition

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
public IList<Student> GetStudentList()
{
    var students = new List<Student>();
    if(getOtherSchoolStudents)
    {
        var otherSchoolStudents  = GetOtherSchoolStudents();
        students.AddRange(otherSchoolStudents);
    }
    var currentSchoolStudents = GetCurrentSchoolStudents();
    students.AddRange(currentSchoolStudents)
    return students;
}
```

Here when the `getOtherSchoolStudents` is `true`, I would like to run the methods `GetOtherSchoolStudents()` and  `GetCurrentSchoolStudents()` in parallel. I understand that I can move the `GetCurrentSchoolStudents()` inside to the condition scope and run both in parallel as shown below

```
public IList<Student> GetStudentList()
{
    var students = new List<Student>();
    if(getOtherSchoolStudents)
    {
        var otherSchoolStudents  = GetOtherSchoolStudents(); // run in parallel
        var currentSchoolStudents = GetCurrentSchoolStudents(); // run in parallel
        students.AddRange(otherSchoolStudents);
        students.AddRange(currentSchoolStudents)
    }
    else
    {
        var currentSchoolStudents = GetCurrentSchoolStudents(); 
        students.AddRange(currentSchoolStudents);
    }
    return students;
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be a invoking your two get-operations in parallel:

```
public IList<Student> GetStudentList()
{
    List<Student> currentSchoolStudents;
    List<Student> otherSchoolStudents; 

    Parallel.Invoke(
    { currentSchoolStudents = GetCurrentSchoolStudents(); }
    { otherSchoolStudents = getOtherSchoolStudents 
                          ? GetOtherSchoolStudents() 
                          : new List<Student>(); }
    );

    var students = new List<Student>();
    students.AddRange(otherSchoolStudents);
    students.AddRange(currentSchoolStudents)
    return students;
}
```

This assumes your operations return a `List<Student>`, if they return something else, for example a `Student[]`, you need to change the types accordingly.